# Not able to upload Plugins/ Theme from Admin backend

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, uploads, dashboard

I am facing strange problem that site admin is not able to upload and activate any plugin from the back-end. There is no option available to upload the plugin as well as theme. I have checked all the user capabilities and they are perfectly fine. What will be the issue? [image: Plugin_upload-button]

Comment: Please check this https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/why-cant-i-add-or-install-plugins-in-wordpress/

Comment: already gone through it @Michael :(

Comment: how do you have installed the current plugins ?

Comment: I have already installed them on local system before moving to client server @mmm

Comment: and on local you have the button to add plugin ? do you have changed the tables prefix when you move it ?

Comment: Yes there was button on localhost. No, I did not change the wordpress tables prefix @mmm

Comment: Maybe it's because it's wordpress business website. You can enable it via settings